# Use find, count or first in parse to test existence

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I need to know if an object exists in the db I'm using. I know I can use query.count to test if the result is zero then it does not exist else it exists.  But someone told me that count is expensive so I think that query.first may be more efficient. Is that true and what is the best way to test the existence of an object in the db?

Answer (score 0):

query first will not count your results you can use query find and then test for the array length using  array.length if more than 0 or not

Comment: I need to test existence only i do not need the number of results

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed some code, but this is too fun a question to pass up.

Test code in a below, but my non-scientific answer is: so long as the query is well indexed, it probably doesn't matter which method you use.  Counts are expensive when you are counting large numbers of objects, but if you're just trying to find one and the query is indexed, I do not think that it'll be expensive.

Ok, so now for some code.  I cooked up some unit tests in my parse-server repo just to test the three different ways I could think of to test existence.  In all three cases, I am using objectId which might be special, so you could easily adjust that.  I also just do each test once, whereas to be scientific about it, we'd want to do it 100 times or so each and average.  But then we'd need to think about query caching, so I'm just keeping it simple and you could test it for real on your own data using the same pattern.

ok, now that I've given all my caveats:

```
describe('way to find if an object exists....', function () {

  beforeEach(function (done) {
    new Parse.Object('Test')
      .save()
      .then((testObj) => {
        this.testObj = testObj;
        done();
      })
      .catch(done.fail);
  });

  it('should use get if we know object id', function(done) {
    this.start = new Date();
    new Parse.Query('Test').get(this.testObj.id)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('get time exists', new Date() - this.start);
        return expect(result.id).toBe(this.testObj.id);
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.start = new Date();
        return new Parse.Query('Test').get('not the id');
      })
      .then(
        () => done.fail('we shouldn\'t get here, cause the obj doesn\'t exist'),
        // so if the get is rejected you know it doesn't exist.
        e => {
          console.log('get time does not exist', new Date() - this.start);
          expect(e).toEqual(new Parse.Error(101, 'Object not found.'));
        })
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });

  it('should also work with find', function (done) {
    this.start = new Date();
    new Parse.Query('Test')
      .equalTo('objectId', this.testObj.id)
      .find()
      .then(result => {
        console.log('find time exists', new Date() - this.start);
        return expect(result.length).toBe(1);
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.start = new Date();
        return new Parse.Query('Test')
          .equalTo('objectId', 'not the id')
          .find();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('find time does not exist', new Date() - this.start);
        expect(result.length).toEqual(0);
      })
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });

  it('should also work with count', function (done) {
    this.start = new Date();
    new Parse.Query('Test')
      .equalTo('objectId', this.testObj.id)
      .count()
      .then(result => {
        console.log('count time exists', new Date() - this.start);
        return expect(result).toBe(1);
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.start = new Date();
        return new Parse.Query('Test')
          .equalTo('objectId', 'not the id')
          .count();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('count time does not exist', new Date() - this.start);
        expect(result).toEqual(0);
      })
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```

which yields this result:

```
Jasmine started

  way to find if an object exists....

    ✓ should use get if we know object id
    get time exists 19
    get time does not exist 8

    ✓ should also work with find
    find time exists 12
    find time does not exist 9

    ✓ should also work with count    
    count time exists 7
    count time does not exist 6
```

So in my nice empty, in memory mongo, its all super blazing fast (those are milliseconds), so, assuming your query is well indexed, pick the one that yields the most readable code ;)